# BigQuery Node.js API startQuery doesn't inject data into destinationTable

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Consider the following BQ query:

```
const sourceQuery = '#standardSQL SELECT station_id, time FROM bryans_bike_analysis_data.2016_status_data ' +
                    'WHERE SAFE_CAST(bikes_available as INT64)=0 AND SAFE_CAST(docks_available AS INT64)=0' +
                    'GROUP BY station_id, time';
```

and consider the following code (placed inside a Google Cloud Function -- removed some stuff too keep it brief):

```
bqSource.startQuery({
    destination: bqDest.dataset(destDataset).table(destTable),
    query: sourceQuery
}, function(err, job) {

    if (!err) {
        console.log("Succesfully initialized query");

        job.getQueryResults(function(err, rows, apiResponse) {

            if (!err) {
                console.log("Successfully completed inner");
                console.log(apiResponse);
            }
            else {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(apiResponse);
                res.status(500).end();
            }

        });
    }
    else {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).end();
    }
});
```

The documentation leads me to believe that the query should execute, then the results should be placed into the table (in a separate project) as specified as per the destination property.  However, this is the error that's returned:

```
errors:
[ { domain: 'global',
   reason: 'invalidQuery',
   message: '1.195 - 1.195: No query found.',
   locationType: 'other',
   location: 'query' } ],
   response: undefined,
   message: '1.195 - 1.195: No query found.' }
```

When I look at the logs, it looks like an insert call is made to my destination project's BQ, it's actually the `getqueryresults` call in my *source* project that's fetching the error.  Inside the error in my source project the logs read:

```
   jobGetQueryResultsResponse: {
job: {
 jobConfiguration: {
  query: {
   createDisposition:  "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"         
   defaultDataset: {
   }
   destinationTable: {
    datasetId:  "destination_bq_cp_test"          
    projectId:  "armalavage-test"          
    tableId:  "bikes_available"          
   }
   query:  "#standardSQL SELECT station_id, time FROM bryans_bike_analysis_data.2016_status_data WHERE SAFE_CAST(bikes_available as INT64)=0 AND SAFE_CAST(docks_available AS INT64)=0GROUP BY station_id, time"         
   writeDisposition:  "WRITE_EMPTY"         
  }
 }
```

I assumed that the destination dataset was set within the query itself.  Why isn't it being resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query string is that it is just one line started with # which is treated as a comment - thus the error message -  `No query found`

Comment: That's what I get for copying the query directly from the BQ UI :/ . Thank you.

The correct and reformatted query is: `const sourceQuery = '#standardSQL\n SELECT station_id, time FROM bryans_bike_analysis_data.2...`

Comment: exactly! glad it helped :)

Comment: btw, you can try to use backquote  around query as you would see it in UI. this is analogue of triple quotes for string literal